# PHP function - what is better structure for an if/else statement?

Tags: php, performance, coding-style, if-statement

I'm writing a function and wondered if it's best (in regards to performance and coding practices) to handle returning conditions like this:

```
public function func_1() {
  if ( true == $condition) {
    // Do something
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

or this:

```
public function func_2() {
  if ( false == $condition ) return false;
  // Do something
    return true;
}
```

Is there a benefit to encapsulating a bunch of code within an if/else (func_1) or is it best to get the quickest returns out of the way first (func_2)?

Comment: This is completely programmer preference.

Comment: Run benchmarks and you'll know

Comment: With regard to your comment "is it best to get the quickest returns out of the way first". If you're looking to improve performance then getting the most common situation dealt with first would be better.

Comment: Sorry for the "not constructive" question. I'm not a programmer by education; more of a hobbyist. Trying to get a feel for the right way to do things. If it's completely preference, then my question is answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any performance different will be so tiny that it will be *very* difficult to measure.

I would generally use the second version, simply because it avoids further nesting if you have additional conditions, but for a simple if/else it might be better to keep the else for clarity.

In other words: use what works for you!

Comment: I'm gathering it's preference. Thanks for the input Hamish!

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are identical except for the negative or positive matching, (if true, do this, if false something else).

Your first example is the proper way to do it, using `{}` to surround your conditional code.

You don't want to write it as:

```
public function func_2() {
  if ( false == $condition ) return false;
  // Do something
    return true;
}
```

It will become confusing to read later on, plus it will break if you want to add internal code to the if/else.